# rollupjs avoid duplicated functions with multi files

Tags: rollup, rollupjs

I'm trying to pack all the common libraries to be used with multiple projects without an actual entry files. Thus I need all the functions to be included in the bundle

Thus I'm trying to achieve that using @rollup/plugin-multi-entry pointing to all the files inside the directory

The problem I'm facing currently is that, some of the files extends each other, when packed, the extended function is duplicated multiple times with the name $n and so on, is it possible to make rollup not duplicate those extended functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bundling libraries inside a `vendor` file is now considered an anti-pattern since you will neglect the benefits of `three-shaking`. It will also come with worse `caching` since every time some lib changes the cache of the whole vendor will be invalidated and, finally, you won't benefit from `http2` [multiplexing](https://http2.github.io/faq/#why-is-http2-multiplexed) that much.

If you still want to do it, in order to give them reliable names (and avoid naming conflicts) it is much easier to do it manually:

```js
// vendor.js
import * as lib1 from 'lib1';
import * as lib2 from 'lib2';

export {lib1, lib2}
```

The previous module, when used as entry point, will result in exporting all exports from both libraries under its respective namespaces, and rollup will internally handle dependencies between libs correctly.

Edit: if you can bundle the libraries along with the project and not in a different process you can do it like so:

```js
// rollup.config.js
const libs = ['lib1', 'lib2'];
{
  input: 'index.js',
  manualChunks: {
    vendor: libs.map((lib) => require.resolve(lib))
  },
  // ...
}
```

Comment: do you have a suggested method suitable to compile all the libraries file together? as we want to separate the libraries from the projects but we don't want it to make multiple instance of the same function resulted from the extended class

Comment: I wouldn't do that but still, the only way to avoid duplicates is bundling every library in the same process as shown in the example. What you should take care about is how are you planning to consume those libraries, are you gonna import them from the vendor? `import {lib1, lib2} from 'vendor'` . Or  do you expect to consume them as you would normally do? Another thing to take into account is: Do you want to create the vendor bundle each time you bundle the application or just once and then use it as is?

Comment: As we are facing the problem where everytime when we need to make minor changes to the library, we need to build every single project which is very time consuming,we're planning to separate and rebuild the library only. Currently inside the project we're calling it this way

import Main4 from "./Main4";
export default class Main3 extends Main4 {
 constructor() {

  console.log("MAIN3!!!");
  super()
 }

 hello3(): void {
  console.log("hey MAIN3")
 }
}

Comment: sorry dumb question, how do I combine these two together?
manualChunks(id) {
      switch (true) {
        case id.includes('base'):
          return 'parent';
        default:
          return 'bundle';
      }
    },
manualChunks: {
    vendor: libs.map((lib) => require.resolve(lib))
  },

Comment: You can do `const libs = ['lib1', 'lib2'].map(l => path.resolve(l)) manualChunks(id){ if(libs.includes(id)){ return 'vendor'} //..}`; but that won't work if you wan to bundle the vendor in a different process than the apps

Comment: What you are trying to do is not easy, first read this article https://levelup.gitconnected.com/code-splitting-for-libraries-bundling-for-npm-with-rollup-1-0-2522c7437697 and then have a look at the `paths` and `external` options.

Comment: Thanks,I will check on that, in the mean time, if I use this only manualChunks: {
    vendor: libs.map((lib) => require.resolve(lib))
  }, then all the function that's inside the base folder gone missing, and when I use the path.resolve(l) method,  it says path is not defined, then I change the path word to require then it builds but all the function inside the base folder is still missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216195/discussion-between-isidrok-and-user3456122).